# Sonar : Anonymous inner classes containing only one method should become lambdas

Tags: lambda, java-8, sonarqube

These code examples:

```
public abstract class Main {

    public abstract void myMethod();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main() {

            @Override
            public void myMethod() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        main.myMethod();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public abstract class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable observable = new Observable();
        observable.addObserver(new Observer() {

            @Override
            public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
                o.deleteObserver(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

are noncompliant with this [sonarqube rule](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-455):

> Anonymous inner classes containing only one method should become
>   lambdas : Make this anonymous inner class a lambda

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two issues you raise are indeed false positive raised by the rule. 
Bug tickets have been created:  https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-553 and https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-591

To detail a little bit : 
When there is a `this` reference an issue should not be raised (2nd case) because it is actually not fixable and I think this rule should only be applied Single Abstract Method interfaces and not for every anonymous class to fix the issue of the first case.